# Can I use an Windows 7 or 8 key to do a clean Windows 10 install using ISO-image?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, iso-image

> Can I use an Windows 7 or 8 key to do a clean Windows 10 install using ISO-image ?

I haven't tried it yet, so I'm asking if any of you guys have experience using a Windows 7 or 8 key to do a clean Windows 10 install ?

I've not yet had the chance of upgrading inside Windows 8.1, so I'm considering the option of just upgrading myself using a downloaded ISO-image.

Comment: No; Windows 10 installer only accepts Windows 10 product keys just like every installer before it.  To do a clean install and to be able to activate it, you first do the upgrade and choose "keep nothing" then if you still want to do a "clean install" when asked for a product key hit "skip"

Answer (score 8):

> Can I use an Windows 7 or 8 key to do a clean Windows 10 install using ISO-image ?

No. Just like any other version of Windows, you will need to have a key for that specific version, which means you need to upgrade from Windows 7/8.1 and then clean install using the ISO, that way you need no key for Windows.

Comment: Worth noting that after you have upgraded your Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 once, you can then safely install a fresh copy with the ISO whenever you want. Your Windows 10 installation will then automagically be activated through hardware identification because it has been activated on your PC before during the 8.1 upgrade to 10.

Comment: Can I somehow get a Windows 10 key online by entering my Windows 8.1 key ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen no. the keys are generic, and you get activated using a hardware ID